# Get the non-zero minimum of a column and its index

Tags: matlab, matrix, minimum

I want to find the minimum value of a column of a matrix of non-negative integers, excluding 0. I know the matrix is square and only has zeros on every element of its main diagonal (i.e. `a(i,i)=0 for all i`).

I have tried this:

```
[best_cost,index] = min(star_costs([1:i-1,i+1:nbr],i));
```

Where `nbr` is the size of my matrix.

However, the index that is returned is the index excluding the zero, not taking into account the `i`th element. For example, my first column is:

```
[0 9 11 5 18 13 14]'
```

so the code returns `best_cost=5`and `index=3` because the `0` element is excluded. However, I would like to get `index=4` as anyone would expect.

Of course just adding 1 does not have sense, as it could happen for any column and, except for the case of this first column, the minimum of the column could be above or below the diagonal.

Comment: Have you considered a work around, like changing the diagonal to the maximum value of your matrix, and then search for the minimum?

Comment: Tex is not supported here, so don't use it here please

Comment: @Irreducible That's not a bad idea, you're right, I'll test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace zeros with `inf` and then use `min`.

```
A(1:size(A,1)+1:end) = inf;    %If the diagonal is to be excluded
%if all zeros are to be excluded including non-diagonal elements, use this instead:
%A(A==0) = inf;                %Use tolerance if you have floating point numbers
[best_cost, index] = min(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment I would try a work around changing the diagonal to the maximum value of the matrix, assuming that only the zeros on the diagonal are to be omitted.

```
%create random matrix
A = magic(4)
%change diagonal to the maximum
A(logical(eye(size(A)))) = max(A(:));
```

And now you can apply your search for the minimum

Comment: OP states that the `0` are only on the diagonal, if there are negative values the zeros on the main diagonal are not a problem, if there are only zeros ... I would throw a warning, this is up to the OP